# Make predictions with an old model without losing the current model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a model that incrementally learns new classes, e.g. n target classes during the first 70 or so epochs, then the original n classes plus m new target classes, etc. When training the model on n+m target classes, the loss function requires predictions from the model trained on n target classes. How can I restore the old model efficiently?

It seems I can do this by creating two separate sessions for each batch and loading the old model in one before training the new model in the other, but this is terribly inefficient and makes training go from taking hours to days.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to use the weights to do it?
Put the weigh of your targets to 1 and the weights of your not-targets to 0

At first, you'd have your weight tensor at `[1]*n + [0]*m` (+ as in concat).
Then you'd assign it to `[1]*(n+m)` when you want to add you m new targets
and so forth.

Comment: I need the predictions to be from the old model - including its weight values. The model architecture is identical at all points of training as I use a Boolean mask to hide classes I have not yet shown the classifier. I think the solution has to do with building two subgraphs, one for the current model and one for the old one, but I'm new to TensorFlow and I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: If you really need to have both your old and your new model it indeed seems a good way to go to have them both in a same graph. Maybe using a kind of renaming/namescoping to differentiate them. You'll probably need a kind of hacky restore at this point though.

TF Sub-graph method is made to extract a sub part of a graph, it's not made in scope way, I don't think it'd be of help here, but who knows....

Comment: I opened a feature proposition on tf github if you want to check:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21402